# Why does jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn not work when I call them inside an if block that is never reached?

Tags: jquery

I know there are similar problems to this, but they dont solve my problem.

I have the following function(#front is a button, #dc70-1 is an image):

```
$('#front').click(function(){
  if($('#dc70-1').not(':visible')){
     $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#dc70-1').fadeIn('slow');
     });
  }
});
```

A simple "fadeout(asd, function blabla.fadein)" works. But I seem to have problems with the :visible thing. Any suggestions?

Best regards

Fred

Edit: Working solution:

```
$('body').click(function(e){

            var $left = $('#left');
            var $right = $('#right');
            var $front = $('#front');
            var $extended = $('#extended');

            var evt = e ? e:window.event;
            evt.stopPropagation();
            var Elem = e.target;
            var $visible = $('.ergonomic img.fade-in');

            switch(Elem.id){

                case 'front':
                    if($('#dc70-1').css('opacity')=='0'){
                    $visible.removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out').delay(500).queue(function(next){
                    $('#dc70-1').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
                    next();
                    });
                    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                    $front.addClass('active');
                    }
                break;

                case 'extended':
                    if($('#dc70-2').css('opacity')=='0'){
                    $visible.removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out').delay(500).queue(function(next){
                    $('#dc70-2').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
                    next();
                    });
                    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                    $extended.addClass('active');
                    }
                break;

                case 'left':
                    if($('#dc70-3').css('opacity')=='0'){
                    $visible.removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out').delay(500).queue(function(next){
                    $('#dc70-3').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
                    next();
                    });
                    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                    $left.addClass('active');
                    }
                break;

                case 'right':
                    if($('#dc70-4').css('opacity')=='0'){
                    $visible.removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out').delay(500).queue(function(next){
                    $('#dc70-4').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
                    next();
                    });
                    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                    $right.addClass('active');
                    }
                break;

            }
        });
```

Used Classes instead of fades because CSS3 animations resolve in better performance than jquery fades.

Comment: Without the matching HTML, this is all guess-work. A JSFiddle would be nice too :)

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the markup that you use with this code?  Perhaps even loading your sample to a site like CodePen.io

Comment: please post the code on http://jsbin.com/

Comment: you could try `$('img').is(':visible')` - please note that it will fade out all images - you probably want to target the ones to fade out with a class

Comment: Even with HTML or a JSFiddle, this isn't a good question as it's not really a question, just a plea for help.

Comment: @Kenny Evitt: Given a JSFiddle, there would be enough to see what was wrong with the code shown (which is apparently his question... buried in all the text) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, you're right; and that's nice of you to want to help. But I'm skeptical that any of this will result in a good question that will be of use to others. I guess someone of sufficient patience or persistence might stumble upon it in a relentless review of any possible search result for "jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn doesn't work".

Comment: @Kenny Evitt: To be realistic, SO is also about requesting help, not just requesting help that others might also be able to use. If you eliminate *these* type of questions SO will be a lot slimmer :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I'll agree that SO mostly *functions* as a means by which people request and sometimes receive help, but that's not its original nor currently stated purpose. And an SO that's a LOT slimmer would be extremely desirous by many people!

Comment: In the future, consider adding `console.log(...);` statements liberally. In this case, you could have easily determined whether the code inside the `if(...)` block was being called at all.

Answer (score 1):

[`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) is a filtering method, it will always return a jQuery object (even if empty), which will always return true. You could use [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead with the `!`:

```
if(!$('#dc70-1').is(':visible'))
```

Comment: Or if they want to keep the not: `if($('#dc70-1').is(':not(:visible)'))` :)

Answer (score 0):

Below would also help without using `!`

```
$('#front').click(function () {
  if($('#dc70-1').is(':visible')) {
     return;
  }

  $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function () {
      $('#dc70-1').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: "Above code improves readability"... hmmmm... surely `if($('#dc70-1').is(':not(:visible)'))` is more readable too (if your aim is to just remove an easily overlooked `!`? :)